# How to use the result of a depedent pair?

Tags: idris, dependent-type, idris2

I am learning dependent pairs in idris and couldn't understand how one can use it. For example, if I filter a `Data.List`, I get back a `Data.List`, which you I do `sum` or other computations on.

```
sum $ filter (< 3) [1,2,3,4]
3
```

But if I filter a `Data.Vect`, I get a dependent pair:

```
:t filter (< 3) (fromList [1,2,3,4])
filter (\arg => arg < 3) (fromList [1, 2, 3, 4]) : (p : Nat ** Vect p Integer)
```

Obviously, the result of filter is no longer a normal Vect. Instead, it's `(p : Nat ** Vect p Integer)`. I read that this can be interpreted as `Vect p Integer` for some `p`. But I am not sure how to do computation with it. A naive attempt the List way is a type error:

```
sum $ filter (< 3) (fromList [1,2,3,4])
Error: Sorry, I can't find any elaboration which works. All errors:
...
```

Hence the question,

How can I compute `sum`, `map` (or even `filter` itself) on the items in the dependent pair that's returned from `Vect.filter`?

(This is with idris2 0.6.0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dependent pair](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/870bc824371d504a03af937f326216302210a875/libs/prelude/Builtin.idr#L100) has fields `fst` and `snd` to extract values:

```
Main> sum $ snd $ filter (< 3) (fromList [1,2,3,4])
3
Main> fst $ filter (< 3) (fromList [1,2,3,4])
2
```